# È "duo" in questa frase sinonimo di "due"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *Le città invisibili* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> «Il viaggiatore riconosce Costantinopoli nella città che incorona a tre rive un lungo stretto, un golfo sottile e un mare chiuso; ricorda che Gerusalem sovra ***duo*** colli è posta, d'impari altezza, e volti fronte a fronte; non esita nell'indicare Samarcanda e i suoi giardini.»

Cosa significa "duo" in questa frase? Cercandolo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/duo/), ho pensato che fosse un sinonimo di "due", ma non ne sono sicura, tra l'altro perché tutto il libro di Calvino è scritto in italiano contemporaneo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il libro è in italiano contemporaneo, però proprio quella frase è tratta dalla ["Gerusalemme liberata" del Tasso](http://www.classicitaliani.it/tasso/tasso03.htm) (quindi italiano arcaico), dove alla strofa 55 si legge:

```
Gierusalem sovra duo colli è posta
d'impari attezza, e vòlti fronte a fronte.
Va per lo mezzo suo valle interposta,
che lei distingue, e l'un da l'altro monte.
```

La tua interpretazione è corretta, in questa frase "duo" significa "due". Naturalmente in italiano moderno "duo" ha un altro significato (gruppo di due persone/artisti etc.).

Comment: Anche in [Liber Liber](http://www.liberliber.it/libri/t/tasso/index.php) si può trovare un'edizione molto curata, in formati diversi, di questo poema di Torquato Tasso.

Comment: Osserverei che *duo* (nel senso di *due*) arriva direttamente dal latino.